# Scaling JSON without root array?

Tags: jquery, json

I have a JSON feed that looks like:

```
    {
      "0":{
        "created_at":"Thu Feb 06 23:44:35 +0000 2014",
        "id":431574171332531234,
        "id_str":"431574171332531234",
        "text":"This is a tweet that mentions @SomeName",
        "source":"web",
        "truncated":false,
        "in_reply_to_status_id":null,
        "in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,
        "in_reply_to_user_id":null,
        "in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,
        "in_reply_to_screen_name":null,
        "user":{
          "id":830531234,
          "id_str":"830531234",
          "name":"ThatGuy",
          "screen_name":"ThatGuy",
          "location":"Awesomeville, California",
          "description":"By @ASomeName",
          "url":"http:\/\/t.co\/Y9LdOHlolz",
          "entities":{
            "url":{
              "urls":[
                {
                  "url":"http:\/\/t.co\/Y9LdOHlolz",
                  "expanded_url":"http:\/\/thatguysite.com",
                  "display_url":"thatguysite.com",
                  "indices":[
                    0,
                    22
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            "description":{
              "urls":[

              ]
            }
          },
          "protected":false,
          "followers_count":5,
          "friends_count":1,
          "listed_count":0,
          "created_at":"Tue Sep 18 07:17:35 +0000 2012",
          "favourites_count":0,
          "utc_offset":-28800,
          "time_zone":"Pacific Time (US & Canada)",
          "geo_enabled":false,
          "verified":false,
          "statuses_count":1,
          "lang":"en",
          "contributors_enabled":false,
          "is_translator":false,
          "is_translation_enabled":false,
          "profile_background_color":"FFFFFF",
          "profile_background_image_url":"http:...jpeg",
          "profile_background_image_url_https":"https:...jpeg",
          "profile_background_tile":false,
          "profile_image_url":"http:...png",
          "profile_image_url_https":"https:...png",
          "profile_banner_url":"https:",
          "profile_link_color":"676767",
          "profile_sidebar_border_color":"FFFFFF",
          "profile_sidebar_fill_color":"DDEEF6",
          "profile_text_color":"333333",
          "profile_use_background_image":true,
          "default_profile":false,
          "default_profile_image":false,
          "following":false,
          "follow_request_sent":false,
          "notifications":false
        },
        "geo":null,
        "coordinates":null,
        "place":null,
        "contributors":null,
        "retweet_count":0,
        "favorite_count":0,
        "entities":{
          "hashtags":[

          ],
          "symbols":[

          ],
          "urls":[

          ],
          "user_mentions":[
            {
              "screen_name":"SomeName",
              "name":"Some Name",
              "id":57701234,
              "id_str":"57701234",
              "indices":[
                41,
                54
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        "favorited":false,
        "retweeted":false,
        "lang":"en"
      },
      "httpstatus":200
    }
```

...and I'm attempting to scale the information using:

```
    $.getJSON('twitter/twitter.php', function( result ) {           
      var curData = result['0'];
      var tweetUN = curData.user.name;
      var tweetWho = curData.entities.user_mentions.screen_name;
      var tweetBody = curData.type;
          tweets = '<div class="tweet"><div class="un">' + tweetUN + '</div><div class="who">@' + tweetWho + '</div><div class="content">' + tweetBody + '</div></div>';
      $('#tweetwrap').append(tweets);
      // todo: limit to 4 tweets max
    });
```

...with which I hope to have output to something like:

```
    <div class="tweet">
      <div class="un">ThatGuy</div>
      <div class="who">@SomeName</div>
      <div class="content">This is a tweet that mentions @SomeName</div>
    </div>
```

The code is pulling curData.user.name and curData.text just fine but I don't know how to get curData.entities.user_mentions.screen_name to display. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "scale"?

Comment: Traverse maybe? scale, like scaling a mountain?

Comment: @KevinB: haha probably. awesome.

Comment: Your code is assuming that only one user can be mentioned. It's an array, what do you want to do if there are multiple users mentioned?

Comment: Sorry, yes, I meant traverse not scaling (as in scaling the DOM tree). I don't know how to handle multiple array entries but it looks like @adeneo has an idea. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

That would be

```
curData.entities.user_mentions[0].screen_name;
```

as `user_mentions` is an array, and if it can contain more than one value you have to iterate

```
var tweetWho = $.map(curData.entities.user_mentions, function(ent) {
    return ent.screen_name;
});
```

and then you could do

```
$('.content').text('This is a tweet that mentions @' + tweetWho.join(', @'));
```

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - There was only one, but added an option for multiple as well !

Comment: It is an array. The format is clearly designed to allow multiple such entities, so we must support that in our decoding routine.

Comment: Then he'll need to change the rest of the code to make multiple DIVs containins

Comment: But then he'll also need to change the code that puts it into the DIV, to do something reasonable with all of them. Like maybe output a DIV for each of them.

Comment: You need to put the `@` prefix before each of them, like in his original code.

Comment: @Barmar - Now you're getting picky !

Comment: curData.type generates the body of the tweet. curData.entities.user_mentions[] is used to generate a link to the user being mentioned, separate from the .content [example output](http://buttonpresser.com/img/sample_tweet.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Using the suggestion from @adeneo I was able to come up with this:

```
    $.getJSON('URL_TO_JSON', function( result ) {          
      var curData = $.map(result, function(val, key) {
        if ( key < 4 ){ // limits the feed to 4 tweets max
          var tweetUN = val.user.name;
          var tweetWho = $.map(val.entities.user_mentions, function(ent) {
              return '<a href="https://twitter.com/' + ent.screen_name + '" target="_blank">@' + ent.screen_name + '</a>';
          });
          var tweetBody = val.text;
          var tweets = '<div class="tweet"><div class="un">' + tweetUN + '</div><div class="who">' + tweetWho.join(' - ') + '</div><div class="content">' + tweetBody + '</div></div>';
          $('#tweetwrap').append(tweets);
        }
      });
    });
```

The $.map function converts a JSON object into an array and assign a function to each index of that array. Also, if you don't add join(' - ') or something like it the default is a comma with no space.